# Chat bot update task module from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams

Is there a way for a chat bot to update a task module using C#?

I have a chat bot built on Bot Framework. It is an SDK-first style bot coded mostly in C# (ASP.NET). I have a task module that uses a form with .cshtml and .cshtml.cs (code behind file). The form has a button, and when the button is clicked on the form in the task module, I want to trigger a method in the code behind file (C#) to do some operation that will update the form (put some values into text boxes). Is this possible?

I found this [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/action-commands/respond-to-task-module-submit?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-1) that mentions "*Use the available information to update the task module so that the user need not fill out all information from scratch*", but I didn't see any code sample for how to update the currently displayed task module, it seems like it's actually talking about sending the same form a 2nd time but with new information.

Normally with this type of ASP.NET project you can do something like this in the .cshtml file:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" id="btnLogin" Text="Log In" OnClick="btnLogin_Click" />
```

And it will trigger a method in the .cshtml.cs file:

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Here's where you do stuff.
}
```

But I tried doing that and the method never gets called/triggered. Is it a problem with Teams that doesn't allow this functionality? I know I can trigger a JavaScript function in the .cshtml file but it would be really useful if I could trigger a C# method in the code behind.

Comment: I am not familiar with the specific setup that you are using but what I see seems very logical and if it was a typical  ASP.NET application what you would need to to is to have an **AJAX** call inside the `protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)` body. This **AJAX** call usually points to an action inside some of the controllers. Hope this give you some idea how to handle your specific problem.

Comment: @SendETHToThisAddress, Does the solution stated above helped you or Are you still facing this issue ?

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT still facing the issue.

Comment: @SendETHToThisAddress, as per my understanding ,updating the same form using button action doesn't seems to be doable. It will send the form again with updated information.

Comment: Thanks @Prasad-MSFT. Do you have a suggestion for the best work-around until that functionality is added?

Comment: You can show a react page in the task module and trigger the function to update details.